# Why does using LONG_MAX in this context work, but using FLT_MAX not work?

Tags: c, arrays, string, floating-point

I have a function written in ANSI C using MS Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1, and the function takes in a char array `lexeme` with space for 20 `chars` and checks for a valid single-precision floating point number.

My function:

```
Token aa_func08(char lexeme[]){
    Token t; /* floating point literal Token to be returned */
    double temp; /* floating point value of character array */

    temp = atof(lexeme); /* convert character array to floating point value */
    if (strlen(lexeme) > ERR_LEN && (temp > LONG_MAX || temp < FLT_MIN)) /* floating point value is outside the accepted range */
        return aa_table[ES](lexeme); /* return an error Token */
    t.code = FPL_T; /* set Token code */
    t.attribute.flt_value = (float)temp; /* set Token integer value to floating point literal value */
    return t; /* return floating point literal Token */
}
```

As provided here, the function works as intended, but if I change `LONG_MAX` to `FLT_MAX` it no longer works as I intend.

The input I test with:

```
1.999999999999999911111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

The above should produce an output of `2.000000` which I save in `flt_value` as a `float`.

```
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.0

0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

The above should both trigger the line `return aa_table[ES](lexeme);` to produce an error `Token`.

My question is simple: why does one work but the other not work?

Comment: I assume that `with space for 20 chars` is a typo and it should be, perhaps, `200`? Your input strings are clearly larger than 20 chars! Also, I don't understand the purpose of `strlen(lexeme) > ERR_LEN`.

Comment: No, `lexeme` is a 20 `char` array and I am well aware all inputs are longer than that. It is supposed to be that way, hence I said it was as I intended. And `ERR_LEN` is defined as 8. The purpose of the function is to take the `lexeme` and check for a valid floating point number. If it is a valid FP number then I store it in the `Token` attribute and return the `Token`. If it is not a valid float then I call the `return aa_table[ES](lexeme);` line to return an error `Token`.

Comment: Yes, "I am well aware" of the purpose of your function, but how can you say that the input is the strings you display and yet `lexeme` is only 20 chars? And I didn't ask what value `ERR_LEN` had, but what in the world the purpose of `strlen(lexeme) > ERR_LEN` could be.

Comment: It's supposed to be a check to ensure valid `float` numbers found are 8 digits. An example is if the `lexeme` contains `0.000000` then the resulting `Token` outputs `0.000000` as a `float` instead of `0.0` as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Too many `char` in array.

`lexeme` is a 20 char array, yet it is filled with  `999999999999...999999999999.0` or `0.000...00000000000000000000001`.  This overwrites memory controlling who-know-what.  In either case, this invokes undefined behavior and examining the rest of the code is simply futile.  OP reports things work as expected with `1.9999999999999999111111111....11111111` does not validate that it will work again.

Insure `lexeme` is filled with no more than 19 `char` (leave 1 `char` for the `'\0'`).

Comment: @Benjamin If this does not make sense, post,the code that fills `lexeme` and calls `aa_func08()`.